# How to Check if an ArrayList Contain 2 values?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

is there any way to check if a collection contain a value or more with better performance than looping twice with contains?

in other meaning something that would look like this

```
person.contains("Joe" || "Jasha");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation of `ArrayList.contains()` loops through every element and does an `equals()` test, so calling `.contains()` twice is *inefficient*.

You could write your own loop that check both at once using a compiled regex [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) that looks for either name at the same time:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Joe|Jasha");
boolean found = false;
for (String s : person) {
    if (p.matcher(s).find()) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted !

Answer (score 9):

Simply use Arrays class

```
person.containsAll(Arrays.asList("Jasha","Joe"));
```

Comment: This is only helpful if you need need ALL of the values listed in asList() to be present in person. The question is asking for AT LEAST one value to be present.

Answer (score 8):

contains takes only one param

```
if(person.contains("Joe") || person.contains("Jasha")){
  // do something
  }
```

If you are worrying about `N` number of elements

```
String[] items ={"Joe","jon","And So On".....};
for (String item : items ) {
    if (person.contains(item)) {
       //found
        break; 
    } 
}
```

**Edit:**

That `||`  is most helpful in your case, since you have the benefit of [`Short-circuit_evaluation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

> The second argument is only executed or evaluated if the first argument does not suffice to determine the value of the expression:

Comment: I know that answer but something that would look shorter

Answer (score 3):

You can also use regex as follows:

```
person.toString().matches(".*\\b(Joe|Jasha)\\b.*");
```

You will get a boolean value indicating whether it is present or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
String person1 = "Joe Smith"; // contains "Joe"
String person2 = "Jasha Thompson"; // contains "Jasha"
String person3 = "Jasha Joesephson"; // contains "Joe" and "Jasha"
String person4 = "Steve Smith"; // contains neither

public boolean containsJoeOrJasha(String stringToCheck) {
  return !Collections.disjoint(
    Arrays.asList(stringToCheck.split(" ")),
    Arrays.asList("Joe", "Jasha"));
}
```

Collections.disjoint returns true if the two collections are *disjoint*, meaning that they have no elements in common. So...

```
jshell> containsJoeOrJasha(person1)
$33 ==> true

jshell> containsJoeOrJasha(person2)
$34 ==> true

jshell> containsJoeOrJasha(person3)
$35 ==> true

jshell> containsJoeOrJasha(person4)
$36 ==> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Put names/strings into a set, then iterate over a person list and check if the set contains a given person (Set.contains is O(1) operation), break if the match is found, e.g.:

```
Set<String> names = Set.of("Alex", "John", "...");

boolean res = person.stream().anyMatch(p -> names.contains(p)); // Java 8 required
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to search each string.

**UPDATED**

```
List list=new ArrayList();
list.add("Joe");
list.add("Jasha");
if(person.containsAll(list))
{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: what if user has N elements?

Comment: Didn't thought about it. :)